# PHP check class parent before instantiating

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, parent-child

What I'm trying to do is to check some class inheritance before instantiating

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}
class C{}
```

i want to check B, C classes for their inheritance before moving forward, if they inherit A then move on, otherwise i will not instantiate.

#### What i don't want:

```
// That's not what i want
$B = new B();
var_dump($B instance of A); // Valid => true
```

#### What i want:

```
// That's what i want
var_dump(B instance of A); // Not valid
```

But i'm just wondering if that's possible here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with:

```
is_subclass_of();
```

Example below from http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php:

```
// usable only since PHP 5.0.3
if (is_subclass_of('WidgetFactory_Child', 'WidgetFactory')) {
   echo "yes, WidgetFactory_Child is a subclass of WidgetFactory\n";
} else {
   echo "no, WidgetFactory_Child is not a subclass of WidgetFactory\n";
}
```

Comment: Since php 5.5: `is_subclass_of(B::class, A::class); // true (of following OP's example)`.  The `class` static property returns the full class path, including namespace.